# Best way to generate all combinations in array that contain certain element in it

Tags: arrays, combinations

I know that I can easily get all the combinations, but is there a way to only get the ones that contain certain element of the list? I'll give an example.

Lets say I have

```
arr = ['a','b','c','d']
```

I want to get all combinations with length (n) containing 'a', for example, if n = 3:

```
[a, b, c]
[a, b, d]
[a, c, d]
```

I want to know if there is a better way to get it without generating all combinations. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So are you asking about python or about ruby?

Comment: Either is *not* fine, you need to explain exactly what you're after. Your question and its solution should help future visitors, not just you.

Comment: No, no it's not. You have to make up your mind. A question that has answers in two different programming languages is not useful and will be closed.

Comment: @Aran-Fey : From my understanding, the OP seems to look for an algorithm doing the task, rather than a language-specific solution. Admittedly, this should then not be tagged with Ruby and Python.

Comment: @user1934428 is right, ill change the tags and edit the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would proceed as follow:

1. Remove 'a' from the array
2. Generate all combinations of 2 elements from the reduced array
3. For each combination, insert the 'a' in all three possible places

Comment: Since I want combinations, not permutations, it'd be okay to just insert 'a' on each combination. This seems like a really good idea, thank you, I'll mark this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of `itertools` and `list comprehension`. Like:
import itertools

```
import itertools

arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
temp = itertools.combinations(arr, 3)
result = [list(i) for i in list(temp) if 'a' in i]
print(result)
```

output:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'd'], ['a', 'c', 'd']]
```

Comment: But it's still generating all the combinations at temp, isnt it?

Comment: But after pruning it's generating the expected output.